# Continuous designed reports in ssrs

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-tablix, subreport

In ssrs I have built a designed Student Card with students information, calling it report1. See folowing screenshot:

[image]

Now, I want to show a whole group of student cards one after the other.

Soi built another report that its data set holds the personIDs of 10 students. I added to it a tablix with a PeronID col and in the second col i inserted a subreport that shows the report1. The PersonID col shows the right information, but the subreport shows fixed students information with no conection to the personID. See following image.

[image]

How do i connect the subreport to the person id of the first col? Or, is this the right way to show Continuous forms?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe in the expresions of each field on the subreport i have to get somehow the parent's report PersonID. If this is right, how do i do so?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are passing the `PersonID` from your table data source as a parameter to the sub report. To check that you are doing this, right-click on the sub report while in design mode, and go to Parameters. There, you can see what values are being passed in. It looks like the sub report is just using the default (or first) `PersonID` based on what I can see.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've either hardcoded the value 129977 into the subreport parameter, or the parameters states something like

```
First([PersonID])
```

Just remove the First command (or as an expression `Field!PersonID.Value`)

[image]